# Problemas con Context en BroadcastReceiver : "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

tengo un problema creo que con el contexto al intentar ejecutar un BroadcastReceiver, lo que intento es conectarme a una base interna sqlite y leer los datos. Esto a través de una Alarma que se ejecuta reiteradamente cada x minutos.

El código funcioan en MainActivity() pero coloco el mismo código en un doInBackground, dentro de un Receiver y me tira error de contexto, ya probé de distintas maneras pero no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar.

Aclaro que soy novato en Android y si hay algo que nunca termine de comprender con exactitud es el tema del contexto. Les dejo el código para que puedan ayudarme.

MainActivity

```
int interval = 1000*60*2;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckReclamosReceiver.class);
  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm set in " + 10 + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

CheckReclamosReceiver

```
public class CheckReclamosReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        new MyNotificationTask(context).execute();
    }
}

class MyNotificationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{

    public MyNotificationTask(Context context) {

        Log.e("Ejecutandose", "tarea");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings)
    {

        Log.e("EJECUTANDOSE", "TAREA");

        UsuariosSQLiteHelper lecturabd = new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(contexto, UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = lecturabd.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(LecturasColumnas.Columnas.COLUMN_NAME_ID, id);
        values.put("username", "tello");
        if (db != null) {
            Long todobien = db.insert(UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS, null, values);
        }

        String selectQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM " + UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS;
        Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
        Integer cantidad1 = cursor1.getCount();
        int i = 0;
        if (cantidad1 > 0) {
            cursor1.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor1.isAfterLast() == false) {
                i++;
                String usuario = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("username"));
                Log.e("Username: ", usuario);
                cursor1.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor1.close();
        }
        db.close();
        return null;
    }


}
```

Gracias por su ayuda

El error me lo tira en esta linea

```
UsuariosSQLiteHelper lecturabd = new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(contexto, UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS, null, 1);
```

Error :

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory,
>   android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

Comment: Te da ese error porque tu variable contexto es null. En el constructor de MyNotificationTask, asigna a una variable de clase del tipo Context tu varibale context, entonces despues la usas en el new del helper donde te da el error. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el contexto que usas para instanciar `UsuariosSQLiteHelper`, tiene una valor null:

```
...
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings)
    {

        Log.e("EJECUTANDOSE", "TAREA");

        UsuariosSQLiteHelper lecturabd = new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(contexto, UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS, null, 1);

...
...
```

El contexto se obtiene en el método `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` y debes enviarlo a `MyNotificationTask` para que sea usado al instanciar `UsuariosSQLiteHelper`, realiza este cambio :

```
public class CheckReclamosReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        new MyNotificationTask(context).execute();
    }
}

class MyNotificationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

    //*Agrega variable para almacenar el contexto.
    private Context contexto;

    public MyNotificationTask(Context context) {
        contexto = context; //*** Aquí debes recibir el contexto!
        Log.e("Ejecutandose", "tarea");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings)
    {

        Log.e("EJECUTANDOSE", "TAREA");

        UsuariosSQLiteHelper lecturabd = new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(contexto, UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = lecturabd.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(LecturasColumnas.Columnas.COLUMN_NAME_ID, id);
        values.put("username", "tello");
        if (db != null) {
            Long todobien = db.insert(UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS, null, values);
        }

        String selectQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM " + UsuariosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_USUARIOS;
        Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
        Integer cantidad1 = cursor1.getCount();
        int i = 0;
        if (cantidad1 > 0) {
            cursor1.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor1.isAfterLast() == false) {
                i++;
                String usuario = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("username"));
                Log.e("Username: ", usuario);
                cursor1.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor1.close();
        }
        db.close();
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, si me daba cuenta, creía interpretar el error, pero había probado de varias maneras de pasarle el contexto y no había podido lograrlo, muchas gracias de verdad !!! me funcionó ... gracias

Comment: Perdón por la ignorancia pero se pueden poner puntos a las respuestas?

Comment: @desarrollosTELLO excelente que te ayudo la respuesta, recuerda que las clases que usen el contexto pero no extiendan de Service,  Activity, AppCompactActivity, reciben el contexto mediante el constructor. Con respecto a poner puntos revisa [tour] como aceptar la respuesta, saludos!.